# Python pandas how to drop duplicates with time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

example:
df

```
     value date_time
     1     2020.12.1
     1     2020.12.2   <--need to be dropped
     1     2020.12.3   <--need to be dropped
     2     2020.12.4
     2     2000.12.5   <--need to be dropped
     1     2020.12.6   <--Keep
```

I want to drop the row if its value follow the same value as previous row(date time).

Is there any fast method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comapre by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift())]

print (df1)
   value  date_time
0      1  2020.12.1
3      2  2020.12.4
5      1  2020.12.6
```

If want test multiple columns for duplicates use similar solution with test all columns and add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df)
   value  date_time type
0      1  2020.12.1    a
1      1  2020.12.1    a <- duplicate by 3 columns, removed
2      1  2020.12.1    b
3      2  2020.12.4    b
4      2  2000.12.4    b
5      1  2020.12.4    b

cols = ['type','value','date_time']
df2 = df[df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1)]

print (df2)
   value  date_time type
0      1  2020.12.1    a
2      1  2020.12.1    b
3      2  2020.12.4    b
4      2  2000.12.4    b
5      1  2020.12.4    b
```

---

```
cols = ['type','value']
df3 = df[df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1)]

print (df3)
   value  date_time type
0      1  2020.12.1    a
2      1  2020.12.1    b
3      2  2020.12.4    b
5      1  2020.12.4    b
```

Comment: how about if I have two column ['type','value','date_time'], I want to combine them to check if it's duplicated or not.

Comment: in you example, I want to use type & value as distinct key. so I want to drop row with index 4 as well as they are exactly the same as index 3.  so might be just keep cols as ['type','value'] ?

Comment: @Niuya - exactly, need `cols = ['type','value']`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df[df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift())]
```

Output:

```
   value  date_time
0      1  2020.12.1
3      2  2020.12.4
5      1  2020.12.6
```